# angular proxy the same endpoint with different domains

Tags: angular, proxy

Hey I have a angular client which wants to proxy the http request to different api servers. The issue is that I have two different servers:

`10.0.0.1:8080
10.0.0.2:8080`

Both the servers has the same endpoint, let's say, `/api/v1/`
When I call a http request to `/api/v1/` how do I specify which server to go ?
I dont' want to call `domain` plus `endpoint` directly. Because that may raise the CORS problem.

------------------------------------------update-----------------------------------------------
Inspired by @Arne, I decide to use the following method:

```
"/server1": {
  "target": "http://10.0.0.1:8080",
  "secure": false,
  "pathRewrite": {"^/server1" : ""}
},
"/server2": {
  "target": "http://10.0.0.2:8080",
  "secure": false,
  "pathRewrite": {"^/server2" : ""}
}
```

every time I call a request `/server1/api/v1/`, it'll be proxied to `10.0.0.1:8080/api/v1`

Answer (score 0):

You could proxy any alias in whatever server you're using it's proxy config. So you could proxy `/server1` to `10.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/` and `/server2` to `10.0.0.2:8080/api/v1/`. Which server are you using?

Comment: you mean give an alias `/server1` to the server `10.0.0.1:8080` and rewrite the path right? just like this: rewrite `/server1` with `/api/v1/`